# If $X$ is seminormed space, then $X/M$ is normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is seminormed space, then $X/M$ is normed space with norm $||x+M||_{X/M}=||x||_X$, where $M = \{||x||_X= 0, x\in X\}$.

My question is, is it enough to show that if $||x+M||_{X/M}=0$ then $x+M=0$?

But I have some misunderstanding because when $||x+M||_{X/M}=0$ it means that $||x||_X=0$ but $x$ not necessary a zero vector.

Comment: Shouldn't the norm on $X/M$ be the infimum over all representatives?

Comment: @Sobi these are equivalent, isn't it?

Comment: @Sobi For general quotient yes.  In this case, no.  Part of the problem is to show that $\lVert-\rVert_{X/M}$ is well-defined, i.e., independent of the chosen representative $x$.

Comment: @user10354138 we can just take $x,y \in X/M$ and show that $||x||_{X/M}-||y||_{X/M} \to 0$, right?

Comment: Why?  As you have written, $x,y\in X/M$ could be very far apart so in what way do you mean $\|x\|_{X/M}-\|y\|_{X/M}\to 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector space and let $||\cdot||$ be a semi-norm on
$X$. Let $M=\{x\in X\mid||x||=0\}$. Clearly $M$ is a vector subspace
of $X$ and hence $X/M$ is a vector space, with the following algebraic
operatons:

1. $(x+M)+(y+M)=(x+y)+M$, where $x,y\in X$,
2. $\alpha(x+M)=\alpha x+M$, where $x\in X$, $\alpha$ is a scalar
   (either in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{C}$).

Clearly, the above algebraic operations are well-defined. 
For any element $p\in X/M$, choose $x\in X$ such that $p=x+M$. Define $||p||=||x||$.
We go to show that $||p||$ is well-defined and $p\mapsto||p||$ turns
$X/M$ into a normed space.

Let $p\in X/M$ be given. Let $x_{1},x_{2}\in X$ be such that $p=x_{1}+M=x_{2}+M$,
then $x_{1}-x_{2}\in M$. It follows that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
||x_{1}|| & = & ||(x_{1}-x_{2})+x_{2}||\\
 & \leq & ||x_{1}-x_{2}||+||x_{2}||\\
 & = & ||x_{2}||.
\end{eqnarray*}
By symmetry, we can also show that $||x_{2}||\leq||x_{1}||$, so $||x_{1}||=||x_{2}||$.
Hence $||p||$ is well-defined. Then we verify that $||\cdot||$ satisfies
all the axioms for norm.

(a) Let $p\in X/M$. Clearly $||p||\geq0$. Choose $x\in X$ such
that $p=x+M$. If $||p||=0$, then $||x||=||p||=0$, which implies
$x\in M$, and hence $p=0_{X/M}$.

(b) Let $p\in X/M$ and let $\alpha$ be a scalar. Choose $x\in X$
such that $p=x+M$. Then $\alpha p=\alpha x+M$, so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
||\alpha p|| & = & ||\alpha x||\\
 & = & |\alpha|\cdot||x||\\
 & = & |\alpha|\cdot||p||.
\end{eqnarray*}

(c) Let $p,q\in X/M$. Choose $x,y\in X$ such that $p=x+M$ and $q=y+M$.
Then $p+q=(x+y)+M$, so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
||p+q|| & = & ||x+y||\\
 & \leq & ||x||+||y||\\
 & = & ||p||+||q||.
\end{eqnarray*}

This shows that $p\mapsto||p||$ is a norm on $X/M$.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the question is to show that the definition
$$
\lVert x+M\rVert_{X/M}=\lVert x\rVert
$$
is well-defined (i.e. independent of the representative $x$ of the coset $x+M$).  Then indeed $\lVert-\rVert_{X/M}$ is obviously a seminorm and hence to show it is a norm it suffices to show $\|-\|_{X/M}$ is zero only at the zero element $0+M\in X/M$.